# Is obligatory put all my templates thymeleaf in directory "rc/main/resources/templates"?

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

Is it obligatory to put all my templates thymeleaf in directory "src/main/resources/templates"?, a subfolder with them,  can not be?, for improve organization

For example, I have this method in the controller:

```
/**
 * List all centros.
 *
 * @param model
 * @return
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/centros", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String list(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("centros", centroService.listAllCentros());
    System.out.println("Returning centros:");
    return "centros/centros";
}
```

My Centros templates are inside resources/templates/centros/.
Is there a way to configure Thymeleaf to resolve these templates?

Comment: No, it is not obligatory. You can put them into a subfolder. As far as I can tell, this should work. Are you sure you did not mistype anything?

Comment: @handris You're right, I forgot change the new route of th:include from my thymeleaf template, that was the error, it works perfectly!!, thanks man

Answer (score 2):

You can tell Thymeleaf where to look for the templates: [Thymeleaf migration](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/thymeleaf3migration.html)

```
@Bean
public ITemplateResolver templateResolver() {
    final SpringResourceTemplateResolver resolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
    resolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    resolver.setSuffix(".html");
    resolver.setPrefix("classpath:/templates/");
    resolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
    resolver.setCacheable(false);
    return resolver;
}
```

Or if you will be using multiple subfolders, just have your controllers return "/centros/centros", which is what you are doing now.